# Eclipse: How to close all children projects of a parent project?

Tags: eclipse, project, explorer

In the context menu of a project in Project Explorer, there is:

- Close Project
- Close Unrelated Projects

Nothing about Close Related Projects. That is supposed to work automatically, but in fact, it doesn't.

Closing a parent project doesn't actually close every child project. Some remain open, especially if they are deep in the subdirectory tree of the parent project (and they do refer the parent project in their pom.xml).

The only solution I found so far, is to be aware of all those child projects and to close them one by one before closing the parent project.
I don't want to remove the parent project completely from my workspace, because that is a project which I need to come back to from time to time.

Are there other solutions for this issue? Perhaps a misconfiguration of the projects, which I might check?
Thank you.